# Get all contacts from sendgrid via api

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm working on a app where I add the user to sendgrid during sign up using the api:

```
PUT /marketing/contacts
```

I also add the user to specific list based on the status(DB data) of the user during signup.

Say I've 3 lists in sendgrid List A, List B, List C

Now I run a cron on every hour and check the status of the user and based on the condition I want to move the user from say List A to List B

As I checked I can add the user to the new list using the same api:

```
PUT /marketing/contacts
```

And I can remove the user from the previous list I can use the api:

```
DELETE /marketing/lists/{id}/contacts
```

But to in which list the user was previously added and to get the contact id from sendgrid I need to get the contacts from sendgrid, I'm using the api:

```
GET /marketing/contacts
```

But this api is only returning last 50 data and pagination option is also not there.

I also tried the api:

```
GET https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients?page_size=100&page=1
```

But this api is also returning me error

```
error:
{
  "errors": [
     {
       "field": null,
       "message": "access forbidden"
     }
  ]
}
```

But the api key is fine because the marketing apis works with the same api key and the api key is generated with full access.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html

Can someone please help me to get all contacts from sendgrid via any other api or if there is any params I'm missing in the above mentioned apis.

Comment: I have been the same trouble, have had you discovery how to solve?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, it's becoming really frustrating. I even ran Arjun tool for finding parameters on a specific URL and it didn't find a single parameter, I'm starting to believe that there really is no way to paginate.

Answer (score 3):

After contacting support, this is what I got:

> In order to fetch all the existing contacts you can use this endpoint:  https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts/exports
> POST /marketing/contacts/exports

This will return `id`, which you use to `GET /v3/marketing/contacts/exports/<id>`, receiving a **file**. So download it, open and read csv. Not exactly what I wanted, but it might do the job for others.

Docs about this endoint [here](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/export-contacts).

Comment: If this is the only solve, that's so so frustrating. Struggling to find any way to send a single email to all recipients

Comment: almost 3 years later they haven't implemented an endpoint to retrieve all contacts of a list from the API, this is a nonsense

Answer (score 2):

I recently went through the same thing so want to add what I did in the hopes that this helps anyone with the same issue.

This is quick and dirty code that I used to test out how to grab an entire contact list without actually needing to open the file outside the script.

```
request = { 
    "list_ids": [list_id]
}
response = sg.client.marketing.contacts.exports.post(
    request_body=request
)

export_json = response.body.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
export_data = json.loads(export_json)

export_id = export_data['id']

urls = []
while True:
    response = sg.client.marketing.contacts.exports._(export_id).get()
    export_status_json = response.body.decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')
    export_status_data = json.loads(export_status_json)
    urls = export_status_data['urls']
    
    if len(urls) == 0:
        time.sleep(10)
    else:
        break

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    out_file = gzip.decompress(response.content).decode('utf8'))
    pd = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(out_file), dtype=str)
```

If you want json, add that to the request body and read it as

```
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    out_file = gzip.decompress(response.content).decode('utf8').replace("'", '"')


    print(out_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, our company is using legacy marketing so i have to use another endpoint POST v3/contactdb/recipient

Comment: They're looking to "GET" all contacts, not create one